# Rails 2.3.9 missing POST payload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, post

I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I am implementing a rails web service. Everything is working as expected for the GET requests. However I am having difficulty implementing POST requests. My routes are set up, I am able to send a JSON payload to the server. However, when I get into the method I don't see the payload anywhere.

In the params I see the parameters that were passed on the request string, but that's it. Please note, I am not using ActiveResource here, my intent is to take the payload and to manually process it before constructing my models.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure the POST request is being sent correctly? Try sniffing the HTTP traffic with tcpflow.

Comment: I am using Firefox Poster to send the request. I have used it in the past, pretty sure that it is doing its job. I am concerned that maybe I am breaking some Rails convention by not sending payload corresponding to a model and that is breaking things somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you setting the proper content type in the request header?

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, I was setting it to text/json. I am surprised though. I was posting to url/resource.json, I thought that by doing this I would have Rails automatically recognize the payload as json.